# Drawing readable text in DirectX 9/c++

Tags: c++, text, directx

I want to display character's names over their heads in my first person game(using DirectX 9 with c++). I am drawing the text in the proper location using D3DXVec3Project to get the screen coordinates, but just displaying text there with a D3DXFONT isn't very readable. It needs to have a background sprite (or some other way of presenting a texture) underneath so that the text color shows up against the background. In short, I just want to draw a dark box texture underneath my light colored text.

I want to have something similar to the text box at the top of this screenshot from "Morrowind": http://nerdtrek.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Morrowind-Screenshot.jpg

What would be a reasonable way to do this? I tried simply loading a sprite and drawing it there, but even if I center it on the text's location, I really need to be able to stretch it arbitrarily to match the length of the string of text that it's accompanying.

Any links, recommended reading, or examples would be much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [ID3DXFont.DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the DT_CALCRECT flag. This should return you the width/height of the rectangle bounding the text, without drawing it.

Using this information, it should be easy to draw whatever sprite you want as the background for the text.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you!!! I had misunderstood how DT_CALCRECT worked, and it was exactly what I needed. I now have names and working health bars done.

If I can, I'll post some sample code later for people who are trying to do the same thing.